# Elasticsearch giving cached result even after 5-6 seconds

Tags: elasticsearch

My System is calling elasticsearch. After updating a document I would like to fetch the same document again. While doing so elasticsearch sometimes fetches cached results (results before the update) even after retrying the elasticsearch get after 5-6 seconds.

I have used `refresh:'wait_for'` while updating the document. Can anyone help me what can be a workaround for this? I would like to fetch the latest revision of the updated document. My query to fetch is:

```
body: {
  query: {
    terms: {
      _id: [
        idsToFetch
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your index settings using `GET index-name/_settings`?

Comment: ``{
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "creation_date": "1553813303411",
                "number_of_shards": "5",
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "DZM_bc6mQoevh2wO7ygP-g",
                "version": {
                    "created": "6030199"
                },
                "provided_name": "x"
            }
        }
    }``

Comment: @tarungusain, looks like you haven't changed the `refresh_interval`

Comment: By default the refresh_interval is 1 sec. That wont be a problem i believe.

Comment: yeah, can u explain a bit more, how are u indexing and searching the docs, r u using some scripts or doing it manually?

Comment: So the flow goes like whenever an es document get updated. A new lambda is trigged. Now the job of this new lambda is to fetch the document data for the same id which was updated from elasticsearch and then update it again. We are using external versioning as gte , thereby passing the same version provided by elasticsearch get. This sometime causes version conflict error. When i am retrying it (fetch and update both) it passes in nth try.

Comment: can you share some example and the version number which ES returns after first insert and version number which your lambda returns

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204407/discussion-between-opster-es-ninja-amit-and-tarun-gusain).

Comment: @tarungusain its been quite some time, can you please go through my answer and let me know if it solves ur concern and if you have more questions

Comment: @tarungusain any update on my last comment :)

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja Sorry for replying late. I missed your messages. Logically the answer you gave should solve the purpose. Though refresh:wait_for didnt worked for me which is kind of strange. Although as a workaround i retried fetching till i get the right version. This soultion worked for me.

Comment: @tarungusain, that seems weird, can yo please provide the value of `refresh_interval ` ?

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja As per above msg provided, we did not provide any value for the refresh_interval. So it should use the defaults which is 1 sec. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @tarungusain yes default is 1 sec

Answer (score 1):

First, you can check whats the refresh interval set for your index defaults to 1 second, in this case: `refresh:wait_for` should return back in maximum 1 second but as explained in official ES documents :

> If the refresh interval is set to -1, disabling the automatic
>   refreshes, then requests with refresh=wait_for will wait indefinitely
>   until some action causes a refresh. Conversely, setting
>   index.refresh_interval to something shorter than the default like
>   200ms will make refresh=wait_for come back faster, but it’ll still
>   generate inefficient segment

You can get the whats the `refresh_interval` set for index using https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-settings.html, **please note it would come in the result only if it's not set to its default value.**

Let me know if you face any issue or have more question.